# mysql strange query behavior

Tags: mysql, sql

OK, I am seeing strange query behavior from one of my mysql servers.  I ran the following two queries on three different servers all with the same data.

```
SELECT t1.Field1, t1.Field2, t1.Field3, 
(SELECT t2.Field1
  FROM thetable AS t2
  WHERE Field2=t1.Field2 AND Field3=t1.Field3 AND t2.Field1>t1.Field1
  ORDER BY Field1
  LIMIT 1) AS MinimumResult
FROM thetable AS t1
WHERE t1.UserID=5;

SELECT t1.Field1, t1.Field2, t1.Field3, 
(SELECT min(t2.Field1)
  FROM thetable AS t2
  WHERE Field2=t1.Field2 AND Field3=t1.Field3 AND t2.Field1>t1.Field1) AS MinimumResult
FROM thetable AS t1
WHERE t1.UserID=5;
```

On two of the three servers both queries return the same result.  On the third, I get two different results for the MinimumResult field.  The first query, returns a small number.  The second query returns what I would expect and what both queries return on the other servers.

I am not sure how to respond to this?  Is this a server config problem or expected behavior?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: try execute the subquery with the dataset that dosent work like a test example I have a feeling it is a problem with colation or someting in that direction. Cos from the looks of it the order of the subquery is not working to your expectations.

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  The subquery works fine if run by itself.  The collation and storage engine of the tables on all three databases matches.  If it helps, mysqldump was used to export them and they were loaded via the script it creates.

Comment: Are you sure UserID 5 is pointing to the same record in all the databases?

Comment: a) Are all 3 servers running the same version of MySQL? What version (or versions)? b) Are all 3 servers running the same OS? c) Can you reduce the data enough to post DDL and INSERT statements that reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is the datatype of your fields float? some strange things could happen in float comparisons.